# Should I say "It's difficult 'to me' / 'for me' to express my self"?

Tags: word-choice

What is more common or more correct (or both of them equals)?

> 1) It's so much difficult **to me** to express myself

or

> 2) It's so much difficult **for me** to express myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) It's so much difficult to me to express myself

```
"It's so much difficult..."
```

You appear to be caught between two ideas. On one hand, you were trying to keep it simple but chose the wrong synonym (*so much* instead of *very*). On the other hand, you were on the right path, but forgot to insert the adverb *more*, meaning "to a great extent." So either/or of the following is a good start:

- It's so much *more* difficult...
- It's *very* difficult...

`"...to me to express myself."`

Again, you appear caught between two ideas. It could be that you simply selected the wrong preposition (*to* instead of *for*). Or maybe you forgot to use commas to set off a *parenthetic element*. The second half can be completed in either of these two ways:

- ...difficult, to me, to express myself.
- ...difficult *for me* to express myself.

That leaves us with four options to complete this sentence:

1. It's so much more difficult, to me, to express myself.
2. It's so much more difficult for me to express myself.
3. It's very difficult, to me, to express myself.
4. It's very difficult for me to express myself.

Comment: nice! explained like a grammar guru

Answer (score 3):

I think we can use these formulas:

> "...difficult for somebody to do something."

Example: it is difficult for him to learn English at his age.

> "... difficult to do something."

Example: It is difficult to learn English when you getting old.

Answer (score 2):

"difficult for me" is correct. 
[The Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/difficult) provides usage examples including "These changes will make life **difficult for everyone** involved."

Comment: Also you would not say "so much difficult", just say "so difficult". If it is really worse, then "very difficult" or "really difficult".

Comment: Correct: "It is so difficult for me to explain myself."
Correct: "It is very difficult for me to explain myself."
However you'll be safer saying "very difficult".   Using "so difficult" requires that you have already provided an example.
If you have been trying to explain something for two minutes you can say "It is so difficult to explain myself".  
You might say "I couldn't tell my friend what I was doing. It is so difficult to explain myself."

Comment: @Readin: Not necessarily. "so" is used as an _intensifier_ as well as a _comparative_.  To use as an intensifier, stress the word "so"  (and/or "difficult") when saying the semtence. "It is **so difficult** to express myself!" The example you gave as a comparative is actually two distinct thoughts. To make it comparative, reverse order and add _that._:  "It is so difficult to express myself **that** I couldn't tell my friend what I was doing."

Answer (score 1):

In short, 2) is your answer.

> It's so much difficult for me to express myself.

---

The pattern is `It's + adjective + for someone + to do something`

You would find this pattern used almost everywhere.

for example

> It is difficult **for** English learners **to know** whether to use a gerund or an infinitive after a verb.

source: [VOA](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-gerunds-infinitives/2722827.html)

Another reference is [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=test%20is%20difficult%20for%2Ctest%20is%20difficult%20to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctest%20is%20difficult%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctest%20is%20difficult%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctest%20is%20difficult%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctest%20is%20difficult%20to%3B%2Cc0), clicking the links pointed out by the red arrow, one would see the same pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In sentence 1, 'It' is a pronoun, and you need to say ‘Expressing myself is difficult to me.’ instead of ‘It's difficult to me to express myself.’ Sentence 2 is grammatically wrong.

Sentence 2 is correct because 'it' here is a subject and means 'to express myself'. So you can say 'For me to express myself is difficult' instead of the original one.

Comment: Ian, your answer is moderately ambiguous. Could you clarify it?