# Learning English is difficult "for me" or "to me"?

Tags: prepositions

**Note**: This post is not about the choice of "for vs. to" in general, it's about their use in terms of "ability vs. action".

I am not sure whether I understand the post ["is difficult for me" vs. "is difficult to me"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251035/109256) correctly. I suppose the conclusion of which is that the following one is more natural.

> "English is difficult for me".

"English" there is a language which could be considered a kind of ability/capability.

How about "learning English"? Which might be more like a kind of action. Is it still more natural to use "for" than "to"?

> "Learning English is difficult for me".

Another wording might be

> It's difficult **for me** to learn English.

I tried [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learning%20english%20is%20difficult&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) but got "Ngrams not found".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is difficult for me" vs. "is difficult to me"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/251035/is-difficult-for-me-vs-is-difficult-to-me)

Comment: The question is the same. It doesn't matter what precedes *is difficult*. The problem is with *difficult* itself.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. Are you suggesting `whatever is difficult` usually goes with `for me`?

Comment: "Difficult for" is followed by whatever experiences the difficulty. "Difficult to" is followed by a verb describing what is difficult.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you. Your explanation is quite clear. Would you please move it answer.

Comment: @czlsws Yes. You can say that something is *difficult to do*, but you can only say *difficult for me*.

Comment: @czlsws Ok, I have done so, with a little elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "**difficult for**" are followed by the complement of the preposition "for", which is a noun phrase of some kind meaning whatever experiences the difficulty.
The words "**difficult to**" are followed by a verb, which is the action that occasions difficulty.

In this use, the word "**to**" is not a preposition but, a part of the verb. It is a marker of the "to-infinitival" form of the verb.

This distinction is discussed here:

[Pearson-Longman forum "to preposition vs to-infinitive](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00069.htm)

"If **to** is followed immediately by a simple **verb**, it is part of an infinitive. If **to** is followed by a **noun construction**, it is a preposition." [emphasis added]